# How to select or click elements on same locator using index in robot framework

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, robotframework, selenium2library

I'm currently new using robot frame framework and having issue with select or click an element with/under same locator (e.g id in this case) 
So, I have an element $id=search that have 4 elements (not a dropdown)

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q9gq.png)

I want to select one of them.

In Selenium's Java I can used like this

```
    List<WebElement> elem=driver.findElements(By.id(search));
    elem.get(1).click();
```

But can't find a way using robot framework yet.

Please advise, Thanks

Comment: Can you add the actual HTML code? This image is not really helpful to help you with the best locator option for your situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the same way as you did with Java, clicking the first element would look like this:

```
@{webElements} | Get Webelements | ${locator}
Click Element | @{webElements[0]}
```

Notice that the '[0]' needs to be within the curly brackets.

You could also use xpath as locator, which would look like this for selecting the first element with the given id:

```
Click Element | //*[@id='elementId'][0]
```

Comment: Thanks @Crama, it worked! 
I confused how to call the index [0] for long. 
Apparently just need to insert the [0] inside curly brackets :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click the first instance of locator, then you can use as below:

```
 Click Element     ${Locator}[1]
```

Comment: hi rakesh, Thanks for your advise, but can you be more detailed? 

I've tried this 


${locator}  get webelements  id=search
click element  ${locator}[2]

but I get this error 
`ValueError: Element locator with prefix '[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session' is not supported`